# How to install a specific gcc version?

Tags: apt, software-installation, gcc

I'd like to install an older version of `gcc` on my Ubuntu Lucid machine. Particularly, I am interested in 2.95.3 or 3.0.2.

Is there any repository to download this package with the `apt-get` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Enter in [this website](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) and select the mirror to your convenience.
2. Then select **old-releases** and then **gcc2** *(for 2.95)* or **gcc3** *(for 3.0)*. You should now see a few versions of gcc compressed.
3. Now you should click in the one that you want to have and the download will start.
4. Finally, you have to [compile and install from source](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/62483).

Comment: This is gcc-3.4. This does not work for me. I need gcc 3.0 or 2.9.

Comment: I am not sure gcc-3.3 works. I tried with gcc-3.4 and it failed. The instruction manual says version 2.95.2, 2.95.3 or 3.0.2.

Comment: The first error message using gcc-3.4:
Tools/bit_vector.h:140: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `ostream' with no type
Tools/bit_vector.h:140: error: `ostream' is neither function nor member function; cannot be declared friend

There are also errors in other files as well.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should now be able to download the version that you asked.