# `apt-get` and wildcards: globs vs. regex

Tags: apt, package-management

**Edit**: Please note, as written below, I'm aware of answers on this site explaining that `apt-get` uses regex to interpret packages' names. In fact, the question is directly about a way in which its actual behavior is different from that documented one. Please read the question before suggesting a duplicate.

---

Some answers on this site warn about using `apt-get` with wildcards (i.e., asterisks: `*`), because `apt-get` supposedly expands them as regular expressions, which might give unexpected (and undesired) results, especially with `apt-get remove`. Indeed, [Ubuntu `man` page for `apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) reads:

> If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains
>   one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX regular
>   expression, and it is applied to all package names in the database.
>   Any matches are then installed (or removed). Note that matching is
>   done by substring so 'lo.*' matches 'how-lo' and 'lowest'. If this is
>   undesired, anchor the regular expression with a '^' or '$' character,
>   or create a more specific regular expression.

In fact, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187891/142526) claims:

> apt-get accepts a regular expression and not a glob pattern as the shell.

I believe this is wrong (at least as of Xenial). For example, I can reproduce the following behavior:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -s 'meld*'
[...]
Note, selecting 'meld' for glob 'meld*'
[...]

$ sudo apt-get install -s 'meldt*'
[...]
Note, selecting 'python-meld3' for regex 'meldt*'
Note, selecting 'python3-meld3' for regex 'meldt*'
Note, selecting 'meld' for regex 'meldt*'
[...]
```

(I didn't remove any matches, only irrelevant parts of `apt-get`'s response.)

It would seem to me, based on this behavior, that `apt-get` first attempts to match given expressions as globs, and only if it fails, will it then retry as regular expressions.

Do I have that right? Have I misunderstood the `man` page, or is this behavior badly documented?

Comment: How does `t*` match `3` *as a glob*? as a regex, it matches as "zero or more instances of `t`" (followed by anything, since the expression isn't anchored - compare to `meldt*$`)

Comment: I don't get that output for `sudo apt-get install -s 'meld*'` (I get 100s of regex matches). What version of apt do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did apt-get install Virtual Box instead of g++?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805440/why-did-apt-get-install-virtual-box-instead-of-g)

Comment: @steeldriver The `t*` match is only regexes in the question

Comment: @steeldriver that's precisely my point. Since the glob `meld*` matches some packages (namely, `meld`), `apt-get` never notices that the regex `meld*` will also match (a substring of) `python-meld3`. But `meldt*` matches nothing as a glob, which is why `apt-get` interprets it as regex, finding the other two packages.

Comment: @heemayl I don't believe it's a duplicate, because I'm asking specifically about the mechanism, and a way in which it might be wrongly documented.

Comment: @JoeP I have `apt 1.2.20 (amd64)`. But I suspect the difference might be caused by my having enabled repositories which you haven't. `meld 3.14.2-1` is in `universe`.

Comment: OK that is interesting. On a machine with the same version, I do get glob results as in your question.  And it's not in the documentation. This doesn't happen on `apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64`. ... So it is an undocumented change in behaviour.

Comment: Just to make sure everyone is well confused, Bash (the default shell on Ubuntu) interprets globbing characters before passing them to any program. If your current directory contains files named `filea`, `fileb`, and `filec`, then Bash expands `apt-get install file*` to `apt-get install filea fileb filec`. You probably *never* want that, so it would be advisable to always quote-protect your globs and regular expressions from Bash expansions, such as `apt-get install 'file*'`. The behavior of `apt-get` you have found is strange and interesting though ...

Comment: Yet two people have now voted to close this question as a duplicate. To the best of my understanding, they simply pointed at another question where the effects of regex-matching were discussed, with no reference to this globbing behavior. @heemayl -- I would love to discuss this if you still believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: Interestingly, the message about *selecting ... glob* is only printed when STDOUT is the terminal. If you pipe the output to any other program that message is not printed. For example `apt-get install -s 'meld*' | cat` doesn't print the message about selecting for glob.

Comment: `man 5 apt_preferences | grep -1n glob` reveals that globbing is known to Apt in general, but I still think this is a documentation bug. It isn't for Ubuntu though, it is for the maintainers of Apt, Debian.

Comment: @takatakatek It doesn't print the message, but it still expands `'meld*'` and `'meldt*'` in the same fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in the [`apt(8)` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html):

```
install, remove, purge (apt-get(8))
   Performs the requested action on one or more packages specified via
   regex(7), glob(7) or exact match. The requested action can be
   overridden for specific packages by append a plus (+) to the
   package name to install this package or a minus (-) to remove it.
```

This paragraph does not exist in the [15.10 manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/apt.8.html), so it might have been added in 16.04.

This does not seem to have got a mention in apt's changelog - [the commit which added this in 2013](https://github.com/Debian/apt/commit/b917917067e757c4479a344a263ef7cf43c00866#diff-3b0d1ae5018f29d3ab4f7f207b6a404cR160) doesn't show any changes in the manpages. This was briefly disabled and reenabled later on (see [commits between May and February 2014](https://github.com/Debian/apt/commits/master/apt-pkg/cacheset.cc)), and [the disabling is mentioned in the changelog](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/debian/changelog#L2550).

So this may have been added four years ago but [only documented in 2015](https://github.com/Debian/apt/commit/9fd6772b202295d7f643bd94681428c0caffd026). And `apt-get`'s manpage remains neglected.

Comment: I see. As far as I can tell, the operation order is the reverse of what's implied by the `man` page; that is, `apt` (and `apt-get`) first looks for glob matches, and only looks for regex matches if that failed. I wouldn't know how and where to verify that (although the links you supplied suggest `fileutl.{cc,h}`, `apt-pkg/policy.cc` and/or `apt-pkg/versionmatch.cc`); any suggestions?

Comment: @JonathanY. maybe I was mistaken about when it was added. See [`apt-pkg/cacheset.cc`](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/cacheset.cc#L318)

Comment: That's a little over my head, I'm afraid. Does that function return a list of matches in global variables, beyond the declared Boolean function type? Anyway, am I correct in assuming the path forward is to open a GitHub issue about the documentation? (Also, as you can probably tell, any suggestion you might have on where that issue goes and what it should specify -- or dare I ask, help opening it -- will be very much appreciated.)

Comment: Since this is Debian, issue typically go to https://bugs.debian.org. I filed it for you: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864811. You can create a PR on Github if you want, and mention this bug number.